# IE explorer works, but it can't display the ie icon in the iexplore.exe itself

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

I have deleted some system unnecessary files. And I didn't know when the problem arose. And some other ie-related programs can display the icon correctly. And this is the `iexplore.exe`:
[image: iexplore.exe]

And the IE explorer works well.
So how can I get the icon of `iexplore.exe` display the correct icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can change icons on individual .exe files by using the registry editor.
Search for iexplore.exe and you will find a couple of places similar to below:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe,-19"

The icon is , -19 as default

Comment: Thanks, but the value of the entry is `-19`. The value is the default. But I found that when I make a copy of `iexplore.exe` in the same folder, it displays the correct icon. But the original `iexplore.exe` won't.

Comment: Check also that you have this key:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{871C5380-42A0-1069-A2EA-08002B30309D}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll,-190"

Comment: OK, it is the same value as you pointed.  Thank you.

Comment: Strange :( I have one last thing you could try. Follow this guide from MS site and refresh folder icon cache:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2422299/icons-are-not-displayed-for-certain-files-in-windows-7

Comment: Thank you, I might be a little obsessive. Though ie works well except the incorrect icon.

Comment: I too get a little obsessive about things like that. I'ts also interesting to find a solution :)